# C# não está achando/reconhecendo minha List

Tags: c#, lista, collection

Tenho uma `List` feita com o seguinte código:

```
List<frase> frases = new List<frase>();
```

De acordo com a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) do `System.Collections.Generic`, meu código está certo. Mas por algum motivo o C# não está achando a `List`, o que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está tentando usar a variável no escopo da classe, não dentro de um método. Por isso não vai funcionar.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Funcionou, obrigado. Não seria melhor escrever isso em forma de resposta? Para deixar mais organizado e também para ficar mais fácil para quem tiver o mesmo problema no futuro.

Comment: Ok, fiz uma resposta indicando a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando usar a variável no escopo da classe, não dentro de um método. Por isso não vai funcionar.

```
public class User
{
  List<Frase> frases = new List<Frase>(); // isso é um atributo, não uma variável local

  // isso abaixo não irá funcionar, não é possível executar
  // trechos de código neste estilo no escopo da classe
  frases.Add(new Frase("Olá"));

  public void Metodo()
  {
    frases.Add(new Frase("Olá")); // aqui o atributo está sendo usado corretamente, não terá problemas
  }
}
```